# Scope Issues In JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, oop

I am trying to create an array in my JavaScript object that contains objects pulled in from a JSON file using the $.getJSON() function in jQuery.  I am running into scope issues where it seems like the array elements are getting set inside the $.getJSON() function, but outside of it the array is empty.  Here is the code:

```
function player(playlist){
...
var tracks = [];

this.start = function() {
...
    $.getJSON(playlist, function(data){
        $.each(data.tracks, function(key,value){
            var track_info = function(info){return info}(value);
            tracks.push(track_info);
        });
        console.log("from .getJSON function");
        console.log(tracks);
    });
    console.log("outside .getJSON function");
    console.log(tracks);
    ...
};
...
$(document).ready(function(){
    var the_player = new player(playlist);
    the_player.start();
)};
```

The output is:

```
outside .getJSON function
[]
from .getJSON function
[Object, Object, Object]
```

And all the objects contain the correct data from the JSON file.

I'm perplexed about this issue, can someone help me understand it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hint is the order:

```
outside .getJSON function
[]
```

Followed by

```
from .getJSON function
[Object, Object, Object]
```

Your outer code is executing before you've got a JSON response, so not surprisingly, `tracks` is empty. This may seem counter-intuitive - `from .getJSON function` appears in the source first, yet is executing second! This is because `.getJSON` is not synchronous. It doesn't execute its callback argument before continuing to the next statement. It immediately continues to the next statement, and executes the callback later.

Comment: Ahh! That makes sense!  So is there a good way to get .getJSON to finish before moving on in the code?  Should I just call the next code from within the .getJSON call?

Comment: @DorkRawk: "Should I just call the next code from within the .getJSON call?" - Got it in one!

Answer (score 1):

$.getJSON is an AJAX call, and is asyncrhonous.  That means you `console.log("outside .getJSON function");` gets called before your AJAX calls return (and populate the array).  The hint that this is the what is happening is that your output you see 'outside' before 'inside'